# Where do I make HTML edits in SPD for Modern page?

Tags: sharepoint-designer, modern-experience, html, communication-site, table

I have a Communication site in which I need some custom spacing and icon-styles, so I'm adding a Text web part, and inserting a table to try and make this possible.  Since we can't remove the gridlines anymore (frustrating), I'm trying to come up with an alternative.  So I'd like to change the table gridlines/border color to white.  It's easy enough with F12, but I'm using SPD to make the changes permanent.  Can anyone tell me where I need to look to find where I can make this change?  I can't seem to find this table in the Seattle Master, or Home files in SPD.

Here's a screenshot (left to right) of my page with Devtools open and focused on where I need to edit:[image]

If anyone can point me in the right direction, that would be super helpful.

Thank you.

Comment: I rarely use SharePoint Designer, but I'm almost certain that it cannot be used to edit modern pages. Hopefully someone with more experience with the tool can provide additional information.

Comment: I'm able to open the modern site (took some configuring) in SPD.  I'm just not sure where I can locate that table's html within the tool.